# How can I get information about the current user from Workbench

Tags: workbench

I'm using Workbench to perform queries.

I would like to get information about the currently logged in user.
In Apex we can use the UserInfo object e.g.

```
Id userId =UserInfo.getUserId(); 
User example = [SELECT CurrencyIsoCode FROM User WHERE Id =: userId];
```

How would I perform a SOQL query in Workbench that returns information about the currently logged in user. e.g. `SELECT CurrencyIsoCode from User Where Id = CurrentUserId`?

EDIT: I thought I'd also clarify, I'm not just trying to get the currency for the currently logged in user. I am trying to query on other records (e.g. return all Accounts owned by currently logged in user). I'm also trying to do this without changing the SOQL per user. I need it to work regardless of which user executes the SOQL.

Comment: You're using Workbench and want the current user id? I assume you're logged in with your salesforce user id. You just need to find the id related to your user and put it in your query as a string.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to perform SOQL query in workbench to get info what ever you want, once u logged in to workbench in top right corener you get user session info link, you just need to click like in image , then you get current user sesssion results[image]

2. if you need to perform SOQL only then first get user id then perform SOQL like below.

   `SELECT CurrencyIsoCode FROM User WHERE Id = '005t000000xxxxxxx'`

[image]

Comment: That works for getting a currency, but say I wanted to query all of the Accounts the current logged in user has. This method requires changing the query per user. Is there a way to do it so it works with any logged in user without changing the SOQL?